# 'Wear the shoes' or 'put on the shoes'?

Tags: phrases

Which is the most correct one?

> - Wear the shoes
> - Put on the shoes

Most of the cases 'wear' is used for cloths or dresses. When it comes to speaking, I have seen some people use both of these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Wear the shoes" would be used when the subject already has the shoes on.

"Put on the shoes" would be used when the subject is going from not having shoes on to having shoes on.

Comment: Hello, BrianaZ. Not the sort of question ELU is intended for (too basic), and answering it sends the wrong message (to eg the 5 upvoters).

Answer (score 1):

If you are walking down the street with your shoes on then you are wearing the shoes, but if you are barefoot and then you want to wear the shoes you mist put them on.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are different ways of saying the same thing, but just as a preference I would elect to use 'wear' if I wanted to be 'more correct.'

I think 'put on' is more of a colloquialism.

Answer (score -2):

The following expressions are grammatically correct:

> 1. Put your shoes on
> 2. Put on your shoes

Comment: What does this have to do with the question at hand?